# Как преобразовать время к интервалу?

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста понять как такое сделать, не могу разобраться как приравнивать время к нужному интервалу и даже незнаю с чего начать

К примеру есть время `1681171205` оно равно `2023-04-11 00:00:05`

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1681171205); // "2023-04-11 00:00:05"
```

Дано интервал 5 минут и время находится между этими временами

```
2023-04-11 00:00:00 <=> 2023-04-11 00:05:00
```

Нужно взять стартовое `2023-04-11 00:00:00` и перегнать его в `timestamp` без миллисекунд

```
echo strtotime('2023-04-11 00:00:00'); // 1681171200
```

В итоге из `1681171205` получить `1681171200` если интервал 5 минут

И тоже с интервалами 15 минут, 30 минут, 1 час, 4 часа и 1 день

https://onlinephp.io/c/a035e

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1681171205).'-5 minutes'));` или +5 minutes, +- 1 hour... date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1681171205) заменить на строку с датой ("2023-04-11 00:00:05") можно

Comment: @InDevX время разное может быть

Comment: а знаете что такое переменная?...

Comment: переформулируйте Ваш вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: @Akubik незнаю как переформулировать, поправьте пожалуйста

Comment: Извините, но не считаете ли вы, что в этой фразе `Как преобразовать время к интервалу?` уже изначально написан полный бред. Время - это абсолютная величина, а интервал - относительная. Научитесь задавать вопросы. Абсолютно непонятно, чего вы хотите, и как это должно работать в вашем понимании. Если интервал отсчитывается от начала суток, то напишите это явно.

Answer (score -2):

Нашел способ путем получения остатка от деления на минуты:

```
$time = 1681181205;

var_dump( date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) );

// 300 => 5 минут
// 900 => 15 минут
// 1800 => 30 минут
// 3600 => 1 час
// 14400 => 4 часа
// 86400 => 1 день
$time_start = $time - ($time % 1800);

var_dump( date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_start) );
```

[OnlinePHP.io](https://onlinephp.io/c/d51e3)

Comment: Вы же остаток деления на секунды получаете, а пишете >получения остатка от деления на минуты